# isConnected() method of GoogleApiClient always returning false

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-play-services, google-api-client

In my application, I authenticate google plus account from one activity and logout from another activity. But `googleApiClient.isConnected()` always returns false. In this case, `Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(googleApiClient);` does not work, it is crashing.

Please see my code below :

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) 
.addConnectionCallbacks(this) 
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(Plus.API, null) 
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
.build();
```

In sample applications, I have seen the code for logout, but there logout is done in the same activity. In my app, I need to logout from another activity.

Please suggest a fix for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Spring Breaker : In the above said link, it is said that I need to add connection Call back listeners. But i have already added those. Please check my code. googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) .addConnectionCallbacks(this) .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null) .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();